# S3 multi small files vs bigger files performance

Tags: node.js, performance, amazon-s3, benchmarking

My application receive a lot of log data from multiple IoT devices.
I have a service that receive those log files (50-200 kb) and upload them to ceph (S3 protocol).
The performance are not so great, and I have been told that bigger files would work better.

I can understand that by uploading bigger files there will be less handshakes,
but is there another reason for bigger files (say 10mb) to improve the performance?

It is going to be a real mess to concatenate those files.
And anyway, if I use the same tcp connection ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html)), does bigger files still improve the performance?

Comment: Not just network handshakes, but also disk I/O from one long contiguous stream vs. separate inodes each with separate metadata and separate smaller data streams.  IDK which factor dominates for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple points on why big file is better:

- API calls are charged per object, regardless of its size. Uploading 1-byte costs the same as uploading 1GB. So usually small objects can cause API costs to soar.
- Each file comes with its own overhead of milliseconds for opening the file, reading metadata and closing it. In addition, many files mean many non-contiguous disk seeks, which object storage is not optimized for.

Also, it's a common problem with object storage or a distributed file system known as Small File Problem. Please refer [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.upsolver.com/blog/small-file-problem-hdfs-s3%3Fhs_amp=true) to understand why big files are the solution.

Comment: thanks, but in the article you sent it focus on SQL searches, my problem is with uploads